# How to handle DB updates when my Drupal source is in git?

Tags: drush

I've put my Drupal installation in Git so that it is easier to replicate the production site on my development system.  Then I discovered drush and I think it's way cool.  But then it occurred to me:  If I use drush on my development box to update a module, then the source code changes will be in git and will end up in production by way of git.

But what about the database changes?  How do I apply those in production?  Is it sufficient to run `drush updatedb` in production (after using git to transfer the code)?

I'm not sure the version numbers are relevant for this question.  Anyhow, running Drupal 6 currently, planning to upgrade to Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, if you update the files on the production site, all you have to do is to run the `update.php` or `drush updatedb` additionally.
2. For migrating *functionality* from staging to production site, you might be interested in [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features). It allows you to export various "pieces" of functionality and transfer them to another installation; this can include content types, fields, views and image styles, to name a few.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Instead of features you could use Configuration Manager